# Maya2018で、PluginNodeのAttributeをアトリビュートスプレッドシートに表示させたい

Tags: python

現在、OpenMayaAPI(Python)を利用してプラグインノードを自作しているのですが、速度計測のために100個近いノードの値を手動で操作したうえで計測を行いたいのに、「[アトリビュートスプレッドシート](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/JPN/Maya-Basics/files/GUID-F821EE09-D5D6-4DD0-9452-4695DFF50FEB-htm.html)」に自作したアトリビュートが表示されず複数ノードの同時編集を行うことができないでいます(デフォルト？で表示される[キャッシング]、[フリーズ]、[ノード状態]のみが表示されている状態)。[リファレンス](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/JPN/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_1_1_m_fn_attribute_html)を見つつ試行錯誤してはいるのですが、まだ実現するに至ってはいません。

どなたか、アトリビュートスプレッドシートにアトリビュートを表示させる方法をご教授していただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
ずっと何かしらの属性を付与する、もしくは組み合わせることで表示可能にするものだと思っておりましたが、どうやら「書き込み(writable)」と「読み込み(readable)」の両方を可能(True)にすれば表示されるようでした。どちらか片方でも不可にすると表示されないようです。